# Sharing a car with an opposite gender for business travel

Tags: halal-haram, practical-islam, work, men-women

If one is going on a business trip and the company arranges me to hire a car and drive it with a female colleague as passenger (or vice versa) what should I do?
Do I explain that a man and non-closely related (i.e. non-mahram) woman can't be alone together (a car is a similar scenario?)

And can we book alternative travel arrangements perhaps on public transport where we won't be alone in a private and confined space or what?

Comment: Salam and welcome to Islam SE the Q&A site about Islam. To make yourself familiar with our site and model I strongly recommend you to take our [tour] and check our [help]. You first question is a what should I do question which sounds like an advice request (hardly on topic as attracting opinion based answers). Your second question is a Yes/Ne question hardly on topic for a Q&A site. Your 3rd question can in first place be answered or decided by your  employer I suppose. I strongly recommend you to take a look at [ask] and use the **edit** link to edit your question to make it suitable.